# Write a Vim command that reads as English text

Tags: code-bowling, vim

Once you [grok vi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1220118), your muscle memory learns tricks like `ggVGx` to delete all the text in a file. Trouble is, `ggVGx` is not an English word, so it makes a terrible mnemonic.

This challenge is about constructing a single Vi[m] command that can be reasonably read as an English word, phrase or sentence. One point per letter.

Modifier keys such as <kbd>meta</kbd>/<kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>, and <kbd>shift</kbd> should be written as they are in VimScript, e.g. `<C-c>` so we can read them, but will be pronounced as two consecutive letters: `cc`, for a score of 2.

Vim commands that start with `:` are only count toward your scrore if they build a word out of non-words.  So `:%s/aword/anotherword/gi` would only add 3 to your score, for `sgi` (and only then if `sgi` is part of an actual English word or phrase, such as `hasgills`. Similarly `:help` would add zero to your score.

No user-defined mappings. Your answer should work on a fresh install of Vim with no .vimrc or other gizmos.

Finally, the command has to do something other than throw an error.

Example Entry:

## cap  (3)

`cap`, change a paragraph

Comment: Are you excluding commands that start with `:`? Most of them are pretty obviously English words.

Comment: ah good point, updating...

Comment: Wait, people still use vim? Don't they know that it's 2014?

Comment: The proper command to delete the entire buffer is obviously `ggdG` (or `Gdgg`)

Comment: Slightly related, someone on SO asked for a way to "insert a space in normal mode," so I gave him a mapping that would insert a space any time he typed the keys `space`.

Comment: @KyleKanos Wait, you mean there's people who don't use vim?

Comment: @Kevin but did you make it so `spaaace` inserted 3 spaces, etc?

Comment: Which brings up another point. We can't just use mappings, right?

Comment: Correct, no mappings. I assumed that would fall under the standard loopholes, but I'll add it to the question to be clear.

Comment: This question is offensive to my religion

Answer (score 10):

Score 60

`:s/foo/bar/incerepellingliceingreeceIgrillripeninggreenpepperinniceice`

> since repelling lice in Greece I grill ripening green pepper in nice ice

You can repeat flags arbitrarily in the `:s` command so this can get as long as you care to come up with a sentence/phrase/word using only the letters c,e,g,i,I,n,p,l,r and starting with an s.

Comment: That's ridiculous. Grilling with nice ice just makes a bunch of steam.

Answer (score 5):

`I think this a really cheesy answer.`

Prints " think this is a really cheesy answer.", score of 36. If you count "anything typed in insert mode" as one point, we can construct arbitrarily long cheesy strings like this:

`I think really cheesy answers are accidents. No really, they're accidents. I mentioned they're accidents, right?`

Where each cc in "accident" is the `<Ctrl-C>` insert mode command. The following i puts us back in insert mode for an additional two characters whenever we write "accident". If we have to end in normal mode, we can finish the paragraph with:

`But I really like soccer!`

Which leaves insert mode, moves to the end of the last word, and replaces the last character with a !.

Answer (score 4):

Vim's text objects provide a variety of three-letter words (of which `cap` is one).

```
grep -E '^[cdv][ai][wspbt]$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

- `cab`
- `cap`
- `cat`
- `caw`
- `cis`
- `cit`
- `dab`
- `dap`
- `das`
- `dat`
- `daw`
- `dib`
- `dip`
- `dis`
- `dit`
- `vas`
- `vat`
- `vaw`
- `vip`
- `vis`

I only found one four letter command that is a word:

- `guib`

I opted not to include insert mode commands such as `a`, `r`, `s` where the remainder of the "word" is just text typed into the document. Otherwise, you would have to accept *any* word starting with one of those letters.

Comment: This answer definitely fits with what I had in mind when I asked the question. No loopholes (standard or non), but it seems a bit odd that they're all 3 characters long.

Comment: Found a four letter one.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't spent much time, but found at least one 6-letter word which is a valid command: toggle (go to next letter 'o', then jump to beginning of file, then second line and to the end of a first word there). I am sure there could be a lot of other words combined from movement commands.

Found another one. This one at least does something (and is 7 letters): forgery (go to 'o', replace with 'g', go to end of word, replace with 'y').

More words and phrases:

```
Brand new
Entangled<space>
Su<cc>ulents
```

Comment: Nice ones! `forgery` especially.